# git の差分を直接対象ディレクトリに適用したい

Tags: git

git で管理されているソースコードをデプロイして動かしている環境があります。デプロイ後のその環境上では、ソースは git 管理されていません。

今、手元で作成した git の差分(`git diff` の出力物)があるのですが、それを、このサーバー上に直接適用したくなりました。

## 質問

git 上で、`git diff` で得られるような差分を、直接ファイルシステムに適用するにはどうしたら良いですか？

## 環境

- centos 7

Comment: patchファイルを作れば良いように思いました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> git 上で、git diff で得られるような差分を、直接ファイルシステムに適用するにはどうしたら良いですか？

git 管理されていない状態でも**git apply**でできると思います。手元ではできました。

```
$ git diff --color=never > diff.txt
```

```
$ git apply diff.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

ソースコード管理ツールが普及する以前は `diff` と `patch` で差分を管理していました。今でもできます。

`diff` でとったソースコードの差分をパッチファイルと呼びます。
パッチファイルをそのまま `patch` に入力すると差分が適用されます。

```
branch_a$ diff -u old_source_dir new_source_dir > /var/tmp/brancha_patch
branch_a$ cd ../branch_b
branch_b$ patch < /var/tmp/brancha_patch
```

`patch` はかなり賢くて、差分元と適用先で、行番号が違うとか、ファジー論理が許す範囲でちょっとだけソース内容が違うとかの場合でも、差分ファイルを適用してくれます。機械的に適用できなかった差分は `.rej` ファイルに残るなどいたせりつくせりです。

元ファイルが `git` で管理できているのなら、最初の `diff` の代わりに `git diff` が使えます。 `patch` のための情報を最大限に供給できるよう `unified` 形式を使うとよいでしょう。 `man git` においても `-p` オプションを指定することが推奨されています（自動的に `unified diff` 形式で出力されます）

まあデプロイ先に `patch` が無いとなると無理っすけど。

Answer (score 2):

1. (レポジトリにて) `git diff 引数forDiff > foo.patch` して、これをサーバーに持っていく
2. (ソースのベースディレクトリにて) `patch -p 1 < path/to/foo.patch` することで、適用できることを確認しました。

`-p 1` の引数は、 git diff の出力は、 diff 引数ファイルパス情報として、仮想的な `a` と `b` を付与しているらしく、それを strip して適用するために、必要となる様子です。

以下が、 diff の中の、その仮想的なパスの例。

```
--- a/app/models/foo.rb
+++ b/app/models/foo.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

`git diff`に`--output`オプションがあります。

```
$ man git-diff

   --output=<file>
       Output to a specific file instead of stdout.
```

**実行例**

```
$ git diff --output=OUTPUT.diff HEAD~ /path/to/file
```

複数ファイルの場合は試していません。